# Data not inserted into Database but getting success message in emulator

Tags: android, json

I am calling register api, but when I run it in emulator it shows succeed, but not data is inserted in the database. Please suggest me what to do perfectly, and how I get response from server side...please give me idea for that also.

Here is my code:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e_username);
        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e_email);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e_password);
        register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn) ;

        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GetCheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot();

                if (CheckEditText) {

                    SendDataToServer(Getname, GetEmail, GetPassword);

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please fill all form fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });

    }
    public void GetCheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot(){

        Getname = name.getText().toString();
        GetEmail = email.getText().toString();
        GetPassword = password.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Getname) || TextUtils.isEmpty(GetEmail) || TextUtils.isEmpty(GetPassword))
        {

            CheckEditText = false;

        }
        else {

            CheckEditText = true ;
        }

    }
    public void SendDataToServer(final String patient_firstname, final String patient_email, final String patient_password){
        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                String QuickName = patient_firstname ;
                String QuickEmail = patient_email ;
                String QuickPassword = patient_password;

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", QuickName));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", QuickEmail));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", QuickPassword));

                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(DataParseUrl);

                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                  //  Log.d("reponse","error : "+d.toString);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();


                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag","error : "+e.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag","error : "+e.toString());
                }
                // return "Data Submit Successfully";

                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    json = sb.toString();
                    Log.d("JSON String",json);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }
                return "Data Submit Successfully";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Submit Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(patient_firstname, patient_email, patient_password);
    }
}
```

And I am not getting any error in logcat too.

Comment: have you tried calling service from postman or any other rest service checking application?

Comment: yes.from postman i got status true

Comment: and is the data inserted in your database when you hit register api from postman?

Comment: you must check your server code if it is correctly inserting data into database

Comment: yes.its work successfully

Answer (score 0):

it lokking like you r using post execute with message it will always display after do in background will finish .no matter what is code in do in background. first you see your api is right use any brouser hit api with all parameter if data is storing  responce any json catch jsone and parsh json data and message when json sent success massage